Chromium distribution 'chrome' is not found at /opt/google/chrome/chrome
Im trying to install  chromium and run the test cases  using the bitbucket pipeline
The below is my pipeline
image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/java:v1.33.0-focal

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Install Playwright dependencies
        script:
          - mvn exec:java -e -D exec.mainClass=com.microsoft.playwright.CLI -D exec.args="install-deps"
          - mvn exec:java -e -D exec.mainClass=com.microsoft.playwright.CLI -D exec.args="install-deps chromium"

    - step:
        name: Run Playwright Tests
        script:
          # Set the path to Chromium for Playwright
          - export PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=/ms-playwright/chromium-1060

          # Run your Playwright tests
          - mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@APFN-1953"

        artifacts:
          - target/surefire-reports/**


But getting the below error
com.microsoft.playwright.PlaywrightException: 
Error {
  message='Chromium distribution 'chrome' is not found at /opt/google/chrome/chrome
Run "mvn exec:java -e -D exec.mainClass=com.microsoft.playwright.CLI -D exec.args="install chrome""
  name='Error
  stack='Error: Chromium distribution 'chrome' is not found at /opt/google/chrome/chrome
Run "mvn exec:java -e -D exec.mainClass=com.microsoft.playwright.CLI -D exec.args="install chrome""
    at executablePath (/tmp/playwright-java-11781585616197118249/package/lib/server/registry/index.js:589:13)
    at Object.executablePathOrDie (/tmp/playwright-java-11781585616197118249/package/lib/server/registry/index.js:597:43)
    at Chromium._launchProcess (/tmp/playwright-java-11781585616197118249/package/lib/server/browserType.js:166:39)
    at async Chromium._innerLaunch (/tmp/playwright-java-11781585616197118249/package/lib/server/browserType.js:103:9)
    at async Chromium._innerLaunchWithRetries (/tmp/playwright-java-11781585616197118249/package/lib/server/browserType.js:84:14)
    at async ProgressController.run (/tmp/playwright-java-11781585616197118249/package/lib/server/progress.js:92:22)
    at async Chromium.launch (/tmp/playwright-java-11781585616197118249/package/lib/server/browserType.js:61:21)
    at async BrowserTypeDispatcher.launch (/tmp/playwright-java-11781585616197118249/package/lib/server/dispatchers/browserTypeDispatcher.js:35:21)
    at async DispatcherConnection.dispatch (/tmp/playwright-java-11781585616197118249/package/lib/server/dispatchers/dispatcher.js:313:22)
}

How to fix it using bitbucket pipeline
Expecting the pipeline to install the chromium and start the playwright tests

What happens does not get save between steps, unless you use caching. Combine the two steps for the simplest solution.
